Can custom agent actions be pinned as default prompts inside agent(copilot) window
I am working on creating few flex prompt templates which are used as copilot actions. Is there a way to pin these inside the copilot window so that users can be displayed with suggested agent actions. Something like how the prompt "Show latest updated accounts" shows up as a default prompt when the copilot window is opened and the Account tab is open in the background.

I am looking to do the same. Have you had any success? sorry, I don't have the rep to add comments yet.. Basically the same as a "Conversation Starter" in OpenAI's Custom GPT if you have used that. I am using Agent Builder, and I just don't see anywhere I could add anything like this. The closest I have got is being able to edit the initial text that is displayed: "Hi! I'm Einstein, your AI assistant. I can help with..." but this is limited in length, without having a "Show More" button, and obviously doesn't include any clickable buttons.

No, what i got to hear from SF support is there is no way it can be done as of now.
